# active connection between OVSDB Southbound Plugin and OVS host

Tags: ip, host, opendaylight

### HTTP PUT:

http://< controller-ip >:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-
topology/topology/ovsdb:1/node/ovsdb:%2F%2FHOST1

BODY:

```
{
  "network-topology:node": [
    {
      "node-id": "ovsdb://HOST1",
      "connection-info": {
        "ovsdb:remote-port": "6640",
        "ovsdb:remote-ip": "<ovs-host-ip>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i'm giving the controller IP as instance IP, it's asking me to put OVS Host ip to connect, may i know what is OVS host IP.

Can i give controller IP as ovshost IP?

Answer (score 0):

should be the ip address where you have ovsdb running, which may
or may not be on the same system that your ODL controller is running